# To set the values in the select options in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have one select option for the drop-down list and two multi-select as well as for the drop-down.

They are getting options from the database and using ng-options for showing the drop-down list.

But I also want to save the static value in these fields.

For that, I have written the code but it's not working:

The codes are:

HTML code:

```html
<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select  class="form-control m-b"
             ng-model="recom.compName" id ="company"  name="account"
             ng-options = "x as x.compName for x in companyInfo"
             ng-change="onSelect()" required>
    <!-- <option value="">--Select--</option> -->
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label style = "position:relative; left:-170px; top:38px">Params:</label>
    <div style = "position: relative; left: 200px; top: 10px">
    <select multiple chosen class="chosen-select"
            ng-model="recom.recoparams" name="account7" id="recoParams"
            tabindex="4" style = "width:880px;"
            ng-options = "y as y.paramName for y in parameters">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-show="recom.radio=='Demographics'">
        <label style="position: relative; left:7px; top: 8px">Demographics:</label>
        <div style = "position: relative; left:200px; top: -20px">
            <select multiple chosen class="chosen-select" id="demo"
                    ng-model="recom.demo" 
                    ng-options = "z as z.demographicName for z in demotype" 
                    tabindex="4" style = "width:880px;"> 
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The controller code is:

```
$scope.recom.compName = data2[0].compName;// value is coming but its not
                                          // shown in the field in form
$scope.recom.demoName = data2[0].demoName;// value is an array
$scope.recom.paramName = data2[0].paramName;// value is an array
```

So where I am doing it wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Your ngmodel is `recom.compName` so use `$scope.recom.compName`

Comment: @SameerKhan That also I have tried, but it is not working, now I have changed in my code also for others to answer

Comment: You will get better answers if you ask about one `<select>` at a time. `<select multiple>` behaves differently than a single `<select>`.  Also it would be helpful to supply sample data so that others can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs:

> ## Complex Models (objects or collections)
>
> By default, `ngModel` watches the model **by reference, not value.** This is important to know when binding the select to a model that is an object or a collection.
>
> One issue occurs if you want to preselect an option. For example, if you set the model to an object that is equal to an object in your collection, `ngOptions` won't be able to set the selection, because the objects are not identical. So by default, you should always reference the item in your collection for preselections, e.g.: `$scope.selected = $scope.collection[3]`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ngOptions Directive API Reference - Complex Models](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#complex-models-objects-or-collections-)